# Jquery OnePageScroll.js get section of currently not active

Tags: jquery, scroll

Using this plugin:

http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html

How can I get the section that is currently not displayed on the screen? I want to change its margin when its `non-current` condition is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this css

```
.section:not(.active) {
    margin:... ;
    padding:... ;
}
```